# What's the converse of "side effect"?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

I'm looking for something like *side cause*, *side influence*, *dark factor*. Googled for those but didn't find relevant hits.

Definition: An influence on something that is not explicit, not taken into account, not declared in the specification, maybe unintentional.

And what would be a better word for *converse* in the title? I know it isn't the right word but still better than *opposite*.

Comment: Your definition sounds like "side effect" to me. Can you clarify how what you are looking for is different from *side effect*?

Comment: @Kit, the same way cause is different from effect.

Comment: As an alternative to *converse* in the title, how about *counterpart*?  (Brainstorming for comparable terms: *opposite*, *antonym*, *converse*, *inverse*, *counterpart*, *complement* — *counterpart* seems the most apt to me here.)

Comment: @Unreason Urf, of course. Upstream. @PLL I think *counterpart* is quite apt here.

Comment: I like counterpart, too - the trick is that two component terms can have three of them, e.g. for "side effect" we can have "main effect", "side cause" and "main cause"; they all *in certain sense* mean 'the opposite'. Counterpart somehow suggest to me that it is not a simple opposite (Brainstorming: *partial* opposite).

Comment: *Counterpart* is it. The *converse* of side effect would mean something that has a side effect. That's related but the perspective is different.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, the term is either [*contributing cause*](http://www.jargondatabase.com/Category/Occupation-and-Profession/Engineering-Jargon/Contributing-Cause) or [*contributory cause.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Logic) I think these two terms are exact synonyms.

Comment: +1, very nice.  *Contributing factor* is another alternative, and even more common ([Ngrams comparison](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=contributing+cause%2Ccontributing+factor%2Ccontributory+cause%2Ccontributory+factor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)).

Comment: A *contributing cause* is a partial explanation of an effect (e.g., part of a causal chain), but not the root cause. It doesn't have anything to do with side effects *per se*.

Comment: @Richard: read the question more carefully. The OP isn't asking about side effects, but the "converse" of them, "side causes".

Comment: I'm saying that in causal analysis, a contributing cause generally means contributing to the principal effect, not a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

With the right modifier, "condition" or "prerequisite" might work: "unstated condition" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Concomitant :

> –adjective
>
> accompanying; concurrent
>
> –noun
>
> 1. a concomitant quality, circumstance, or thing.

From: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concomitant

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a word for what you are seeking -- the "converse" or "counterpart" of [*side effect*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/side%20effects) (M-W) -- other than *cause* itself.

A given action (e.g., receiving chemotherapy treatments) could "cause" a variety of effects, some positive (e.g., tumors shrink, cancer goes into remission) and some negative (e.g., your hair falls out, fatigue, nausea). The single action "causes" both positive and negative effects. They don't have separate causes, at least at this level of discourse.

If you want to convey the sense of an effect or consequence being unintended, you could consider *unintended cause*: The action X was the *unintended cause* of the effect Y, i.e., X caused Y, but Y was not intended.